# Crossfilter.js and dc.js barchart issues

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm working with [crossfilter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) and [dc.js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) and I want to make something like this :

[image]

So, after creating the dimension and the group:

`var Time1 = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.Dep_Time1; });
 var FlightsByTime1 = Time1.group();`

I tried to draw a barchart just like this :

`var Time1Chart = dc.barChart("#Time1-chart");`

Here is its definiton :

```
Time1Chart

        .height(160)
        .transitionDuration(1000)
        .dimension(Time1)
        .group(FlightsByTime1)
        .brushOn(true)
        .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50})
        .centerBar(false)
        .gap(1)
        .elasticY(true)
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(Time1))                          
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
        .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
        .ordering(function(d){return d.value;})
        .yAxis().tickFormat(d3.format("f"));
```

And I get this result :

[image]

**The problems :**

**.** As you can see, in axis values I have a lot of data ... :s

**.** I don't have the brush, despite brushOn(true)

**.** I want to segment the axis like in the example, 2 hours by 2 hours

Please who can help me tho achieve the above ?

Comment: Looks like your time group is defined at the wrong level of aggregation. For people to best be able to help you, it would be good if you could put together a working example. Here is a JSFiddle with the necessary libraries loaded that you could start from: https://jsfiddle.net/esjewett/jusjkm8j/

Comment: For future reference, please note the fixed dc.js tag.

Comment: @Gordon okaaaay chief

Comment: yep, looks like you've asked a lot of good questions this year, but since dc is a command line desk calculator utility for unix, no one has answered. i follow dc.js pretty closely when i have time.

Comment: It's okay with this question, I found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** First we should create the crossfilter instance.

```
var ndx = crossfilter(dataSet);
```

**2.** Then we should create the dimension.

```
var Time1 = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.Dep_Time1.getHours() + d.Dep_Time1.getMinutes() / 60; });
```

**3.** Then we should group the result.

```
var FlightsByTime1 = Time1.group(Math.floor);
```

**4.** Then we create the chart.

```
Time1Chart = dc.barChart("#Time1-chart");
```

**5.** Finally give the definiton of the chart

```
Time1Chart

        .height(133)
        .transitionDuration(1000)
        .dimension(Time1)
        .group(FlightsByTime1)
        .brushOn(true)
        .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50})
        .centerBar(false)
        .gap(1)
        .elasticY(true)
        .x(d3.scale.linear() 
        .domain([0, 24]) 
        .rangeRound([0, 10 * 24]))                      
        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
        .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
        .ordering(function(d){return d.value;})
        .yAxis().tickFormat(d3.format("f"));
```